# Lodash sort/order array by property

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a following array of objects:

```
var tasks = [
   { importance: 'moderate', task: 'do laundry' },
   { importance: 'critical', task: 'brush teeth' },
   { importance: 'important', task: 'buy milk' },
   { importance: 'unimportant', task: 'wash car' },
];
```

How can I use lodash sort or order functions to order my array by level of importance ?

Comment: you better add some integer value to mart the importance value. That would make it easy to sort

Comment: first of all, change the importance value in to something sortable (e.g. integers) and then do something like `_.orderBy(tasks, ['user'], ['asc']);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it without lodash:

```js
var tasks = [
   { importance: 'moderate', task: 'do laundry' },
   { importance: 'critical', task: 'brush teeth' },
   { importance: 'important', task: 'buy milk' },
   { importance: 'unimportant', task: 'wash car' },
];

var priorityIndex = {unimportant: 1, moderate: 2, important: 3, critical: 4};

tasks.sort((a, b) =>  priorityIndex[a.importance] - priorityIndex[b.importance]);

console.log(tasks);
```

Comment: Wrong comment.. You have my +1

Comment: Nice! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 2):

first of all, change the `importance` value in to something sortable (e.g. integers):

```
const critical    = 1;
const important   = 2;
const moderate    = 3;
const unimportant = 4;

var tasks = [
   { importance: moderate,    task: 'do laundry' },
   { importance: critical,    task: 'brush teeth' },
   { importance: important,   task: 'buy milk' },
   { importance: unimportant, task: 'wash car' },
];`
```

and then do something like:

`_.orderBy(tasks, ['importance'], ['asc']);`